# Android Google map application by Android studio which key to include and recommandation

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

When added Google map activity from Android studio. It generates couple of files. Among them my confusion about:-

/app/src/debug/res/values/google_maps_api.xml
/app/src/release/res/values/google_maps_api.xml

Both has instruction to generate api key. Both generate different keys. Both works in the emulator.

Can I just copy api key value and include in AndroidManifest file and delete them? Because after all these values are always retrievable from https://console.developers.google.com/

Or do I need to keep these files as is?

My assumption for development purpose I continue to use debug key. But when I'm ready to submit app to play store, I have to use release key.

Am I right?

What is the recommendation?

Comment: was my answer useful?

Comment: Come on @masiboo, close the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want you can delete this files and copy key directly in AndroidManufest.xml, but it's not fun to change it every time you will release new version in store.

I recommend to use gradle build types for automatically key changing in test and release builds.

In AndroidManifest you pass variable

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="${MAP_KEY}" />
```

And then in build.gradle

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        ...
        manifestPlaceholders = [MAP_KEY: "MAP_RELEASE_KEY"]
    }
    debug {
        ...
        manifestPlaceholders = [MAP_KEY: "MAP_DEBUG_KEY"]
    }
}
```

Of course you could pass here string resources

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        ...
        manifestPlaceholders = [MAP_KEY: "@string/map_release_key"]
    }
    debug {
        ...
        manifestPlaceholders = [MAP_KEY: "@string/map_debug_key"]
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also have a release and debug manifest that get merged at build time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can delete that.

If map doesn't displayed, Logcat will show the error with SHA1 and package name.

you can copy the SHA1 and package name from log cat and paste that in below link.

https://console.developers.google.com/project/still-vim-102211/apiui/credential?keyType=CLIENT_SIDE_ANDROID&r=SHA1;com.example.packagename